# How do I inncrease unity dash icon sizes or set 720p but view movies in 1080p?

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash, resolution

I would like to use 11.10 on my TV as a Mediacenter and more. The problem is that when I sit on my couch the icons in Unity dash (expanded, viewing all installed apps) are too small. Now I am wondering if one can increase their size, or if it is possible to just set the screen resoluton to 720p but (how?) view full hd movies in 1080p switching to 1080p in a easy way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may be tricky due to Unity not having too many customization options at the moment.

Also, I would suggest you to have a look at MythTV/Mythbuntu, XBMC or some other media-center software - they may be much better suited for what you're trying to do, including UI built for [10-foot user experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10-foot_user_interface), ability to control them with a remote etc.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Actually xbmc is what I am using for the mediacenter part (video/pictures/music...) But the problem comes wile working on the desktop; starting games or applications, which are too small to be "recognized/read" from the couch. Any ideas how to get/use larger icons? And if I set the screen resolution to 720p, so they can be read betther, then for watching movies with the webbrowser in full hd, does anyone know an easy way to switch the resolution?

Comment: Just a thought: If you can't see icons from your couch - are you sure you can tell the difference between 720p and 1080p from the same distance?

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Its not that I can not see the icons, its about understanding/see what they are for, therefore, to be able to read the name on the icon. Anyone has an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Just want to say that I tried with Gnome Shell to increase the icon size and also its font size and I got it to work very quick tweaking /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css . Too bad one can't do it with Unity. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can give *Ubuntu Tweak* a try. I used it to *decrease* the icon size, but you can do the opposite as well.

You can install it through adding the PPA to your system (`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`) and installing it via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of the icons by opening Compiz Config Settings Manager, selecting Ubuntu Unity Plugin, going to the 'Experimental' tab then changing the 'Launcher icon size' slider